# How to plot a dataframe using another color for each value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I would like to plot for each value from my dataframe a different axvspan function.

My df to plot a simple curve:

```
date_time                   value   End_DateTime                Duration(Min)
2020-09-08 13:05:08.506633      5   2020-09-08 13:05:08.847000  0.005673
2020-09-08 13:05:08.847000      15  2020-09-08 13:05:39.176823  0.505497
2020-09-08 13:05:39.176823      20  2020-09-08 13:05:40.785900  0.026818
2020-09-08 13:05:40.785900      25  2020-09-08 13:05:41.091760  0.005098
2020-09-08 13:05:41.091760      30  2020-09-08 13:06:26.207699  0.751932
2020-09-08 13:06:26.207699      35  2020-09-08 13:08:31.656359  2.090811
2020-09-08 13:08:31.656359      40  2020-09-08 13:24:19.688665  15.800538
2020-09-08 13:24:19.688665      45  2020-09-08 13:24:25.853547  0.102748
2020-09-08 13:24:25.853547      47  2020-09-08 13:24:26.824579  0.016184
2020-09-08 13:24:26.824579      55  2020-09-08 13:24:27.788014  0.016057
2020-09-08 13:24:27.788014      5   2020-09-08 13:24:28.143081  0.005918
```

And for each value, I would like to plot axvspan with start = date_time and end = end_datetime with a color for each value. So I tried this :

```
data = df #create unique list of names

UniqueNames = data.value.unique()

#create a data frame dictionary to store your data frames
DataFrameDict_axvspan = {elem : pd.DataFrame for elem in UniqueNames}

for key in DataFrameDict_axvspan.keys():
    DataFrameDict_axvspan[key] = data[:][data.value == key]
```

and:

```
df.plot('date_time', 'value', figsize=(16, 8), label="G7", drawstyle="steps-post") 

for i in DataFrameDict_axvspan:
    plt.axvspan(i[0],i[1], facecolor='orange', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

My main problem is to plot axvspan with a different color for each value...
PS : With this df, there is 2 value = 5, so it must be 2 area with the same color.

**EDITH**

[image]

when I use your method it works except for small changes in values, the color doesn't change, i think it's due to normalization, is there a way to take these small changes into account anyway with colors ?

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: see edition @jojo

Comment: The circumstance that small changes are barely visible is a direct consequence of the fact the mapping is linear, as I mentioned below. This is something you can address, for example, with [listed-colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#creating-listed-colormaps). I'll add an example to the answer. Note, however, that the more you adapt the colormap, the less genuine your solution will become.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Maybe, as a first attempt, try changing the colormap. Use 'prism' instead of 'viridis' for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note that your `DataFrameDict_axvspan` contains at some point data from the `value` column as keys and for all of them the class `pd.DataFrame` as values. I doubt this is what you want. Simply write `DataFrameDict_axvspan = dict()` and populate the dict in the for-loop:*

```py
data = df #create unique list of names

uniques = data.value.unique()

#create a data frame dictionary to store your data frames
dfdict_axvspan = {}  # this is your DataFrameDict_axvspan

for key in uniques:
    dfdict_axvspan[key] = ...
```

*However, I'm not sure if why you would need all of this to plot axvspan's with colors based on the *value* column of your df...
Mabye simply have a look at the example below and try this directly with your *df*:*

---

One way to associate colors to values is with colormaps, [matplotlib has quite a few](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

If you are not familiar with colormaps in matplotlib, the idea behind them is to associate color-flows to the numerical interval [0, 1]. In general the mapping is linear, however, [other relations are possible](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html).

To account for values from an arbitrary interval, it is also straightforward to map the data range to the unit interval with [Normalize](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize).

So one way to approach your problem could be by mapping the data range of your `value` column to a colormap. The colormap 'viridis', used below is just as an example, [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#miscellaneous) you can find others. An implementation might look a little like this:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize


class ColoredValues():
    """Colormap for arbitrary values"""
    def __init__(self, cmap: str, vmin, vmax):
        self._cmap = cm.get_cmap(cmap)
        self._norm = Normalize(vmin, vmax)
    
    def get_color(self, value):
        return self._cmap(self._norm(value))

# get the data range
vmin, vmax = df['value'].min(), df['value'].max()
# initiate the colormap 'viridis' is just an example
cv = ColoredValues('viridis', vmin, vmax)

# now the plotting could look something like this:
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    plt.axvspan(row['date_time'],row['End_DateTime'], 
                facecolor=cv.get_color(row['value']),
                alpha=0.5)
```

*Hope this is enough to get you started!*

---

**Addedndum**

Small changes in the values might lead to similar colors which can be difficult to disentangle.

As a first approach to address this you could simply try out colormaps with stronger fluctuations in color, like the `'prism'` colormap for example.
If this does not lead to satisfying results then one way to address this problem is with [listed-colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#creating-listed-colormaps). This approach consists in generating a colormap from a list of colors. This allows to change single colors in this list before generating the colormap. In fact, we can actually use a colormap to generate this list of colors, that is then used to generate a custom colormap:

Here is how this could look in your case.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import (Normalize, to_rgba,
                               ListedColormap)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

# just the same as before...
class ColoredValues():
    """Colormap for arbitrary values"""
    def __init__(self, cmap: str, vmin, vmax):
        self._cmap = cm.get_cmap(cmap)
        self._norm = Normalize(vmin, vmax)
    
    def get_color(self, value):
        return self._cmap(self._norm(value))

# get the data range
vmin, vmax = df['value'].min(), df['value'].max()

# HERE we create a colormap as basis for the list of colors
refcmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis', int(vmax))
# create the list of colors (the +1 is just to map your values to the index)
colorlist = refcmap(np.linspace(0, 1, int(vmax) + 1))  
# now you can change single colors in the list
colorlist[10] = to_rgba('blue')
colorlist[47] = to_rgba('green')
# now, we create a custom colormap from this list of colors
newcmp = ListedColormap(colorlist)

# initiate the colormap this time directly passing newcmp
cv = ColoredValues(newcmp, vmin, vmax)

# now the plotting could look something like this:
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    plt.axvspan(row['date_time'],row['End_DateTime'], 
                facecolor=cv.get_color(row['value']),
                alpha=0.5)
```